# PySpark DataFrame - Append Random Permutation of a Single Column

Tags: dataframe, random, pyspark

I'm using PySpark (a new thing for me). Now, suppose I Have the following table:

`+-------+-------+----------+
| Col1  | Col2  | Question |
+-------+-------+----------+
| val11 | val12 | q1       |
| val21 | val22 | q2       |
| val31 | val32 | q3       |
+-------+-------+----------+`

and I would like to append to it a new column, `random_qustion` which is in fact a permutation of the values in the `Question` column, so the result might look like this:

`+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+
| Col1  | Col2  | Question | random_question |
+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+
| val11 | val12 | q1       | q2              |
| val21 | val22 | q2       | q3              |
| val31 | val32 | q3       | q1              |
+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+`

I'v tried to do that as follow:
`python
df.withColumn(
    'random_question'
    ,df.orderBy(rand(seed=0))['question']
    ).createOrReplaceTempView('with_random_questions')`

The problem is that the above code does append the required column but WITHOUT permuting the values in it.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thank you,

Gilad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

questions = df.select(F.col('Question').alias('random_question'))
random = questions.orderBy(F.rand())
```

Give the dataframes a unique row id:

```
df = df.withColumn('row_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
random = random.withColumn('row_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Join them by row id:

```
final_df = df.join(random, 'row_id')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works. Could you explain also why my attempt failed?

Comment: No worries!
I am not 100% sure as to why your attempt failed, and I don't want to make a false statement hanging out on the web :)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is wrong. You are not guaranteed to have the same set of ids in the two dataframes and you will lose rows.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[10,11,12,13],'c':[100,101,102,103]}))
questions = df.select(F.col('a').alias('random_question'))
random = questions.orderBy(F.rand())
df = df.withColumn('row_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
random = random.withColumn('row_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
random.show()
```

output on my system:

```
+---+---+---+-----------+
|  a|  b|  c|     row_id|
+---+---+---+-----------+
|  1| 10|100| 8589934592|
|  2| 11|101|25769803776|
|  3| 12|102|42949672960|
|  4| 13|103|60129542144|
+---+---+---+-----------+

+---------------+-----------+
|random_question|     row_id|
+---------------+-----------+
|              4|          0|
|              1| 8589934592|
|              2|17179869184|
|              3|25769803776|
+---------------+-----------+
```

Use the following utility to add permuted columns in place of the original columns or as new columns

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, col
from pyspark.sql import Row
def permute_col_maintain_corr_join(df, colnames,  newnames=[], replace = False):
    '''
    colname: list of columns to be permuted
    newname: list of new names for the permuted columns
    replace: whether to add permuted columns as new columns or replace the original columne
    '''
    def flattener(rdd_1):
        r1 = rdd_1[0].asDict()
        idx = rdd_1[1]
        combined_dict = {**r1,**{'index':idx}}
        out_row = Row(**combined_dict)
        return out_row
    def compute_schema_wid(df):
        dfs = df.schema.fields
        ids = StructField('index', IntegerType(), False)
        return StructType(dfs+[ids])
    if not newnames:
        newnames = [f'{i}_sha' for i in colnames]
    assert len(colnames) == len(newnames)
    if not replace:
        assert not len(set(df.columns).intersection(set(newnames))), 'with replace False newnames cannot contain a column name from df'
    else:
        _rc = set(df.columns) - set(colnames)
        assert not len(_rc.intersection(set(newnames))), 'with replace True newnames cannot contain a column name from df other than one from colnames'
    df_ts = df.select(*colnames).toDF(*newnames)
    if replace:
        df = df.drop(*colnames)
    df_ts = df_ts.orderBy(rand())
    df_ts_s = compute_schema_wid(df_ts)
    df_s = compute_schema_wid(df)
    df_ts = df_ts.rdd.zipWithUniqueId().map(flattener).toDF(schema=df_ts_s)
    df = df.rdd.zipWithUniqueId().map(flattener).toDF(schema=df_s)
    df = df.join(df_ts,on='index').drop('index')
    return df
```